# Coordinate becomes negative after matrix multiplication with only positive values?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry

Given a point in space, and a 3x3 rotation matrix you'll have to rotate the point around the y-axis by phi angles. After checking the formula I wonder.. how did Z (third coordinate) become negative? Following the rules of matrix multiplication I see no way a number can become negative if multiplied with only positives..
[formula image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1zPC.png) & [donut.c - resource article](https://www.a1k0n.net/2011/07/20/donut-math.html)

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: I'm guessing that they wanted to change the position of the z coordinate? In this case we're dealing with projection of 3d objects inside a 2d screen so they might've wanted to move it in front of the camera or something... not sure